# Hide Sidebar on _layouts pages

Tags: javascript, quick-launch

I am trying to hide the sidebar on administration pages in SP 2010. To do this, I am trying to use the following Javascript code which does not seem to be working.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("_layouts") > -1) {
       var elem = document.getElementById("v5-page-column-sidebar");
       elem.style.display="none";
       var elem2 = document.getElementById("v5-page-column-main");
       elem2.style.width="100%;
    }
});
```

Can anyone help out?

Comment: v5? isn't it v4 in SP2010? (first-glance guess, here, haven't got my VMs to hand).

Comment: Indeed, it is v4. This must be using this: http://kyleschaeffer.com/sharepoint/v5-responsive-html5-master-page/

Comment: Yes. I am using the V5 as my base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all this, it was a matter of a simple quotation missing.

The code should have been:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("_layouts") > -1) {
       var elem = document.getElementById("v5-page-column-sidebar");
       elem.style.display="none";
       var elem2 = document.getElementById("v5-page-column-main");
       elem2.style.width="100%";
       elem2.style.paddingRight="0";
    }
});
```

It may not be pretty but it works. Thanks to everyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `$(document).ready()` try using the SP function for this:

`_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("FunctionName");`

See: http://www.stephanrocks.com/2011/10/05/_spbodyonloadfunctionnames-in-sharepoint-vs-jquerys-document-ready/

Also see: [Risk of conflict between jQuery document ready and _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30500/risk-of-conflict-between-jquery-document-ready-and-spbodyonloadfunctionnames)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but it made no difference.
Here is the code:
`code`
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hideSidebar");

function hideSidebar() {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("_layouts") != -1) {
       jQuery("#v5-page-column-sidebar").hide();
       jQuery("#v5-page-column-main").css({"width","100%"});
    }
}
`code`

Comment: I'm not a javascript expert by any means, but I think you have to declare the function before pushing it to the stack/queue (not sure what it is).

Comment: It looks like the author of the link you posted did it this way. I tried to move the _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hideSidebar");
 after the function with no change. I can't tell from the original post, but should it be outside of the script tag?

Comment: That he did. I was comparing it to code here. I don't know to be honest. One thing I will note after looking at the code on the page you provided in the other comment is, the reason Vardhaman suggested using 'jQuery(document)' instead of '$(document)' is some of the SP JS uses the '$'. I see all the rest of your JS uses '$'. Can't say that's causing this issue, but something to be aware of.

Comment: No, it's inside the script tag. Just the code I have here declared all the functions first. I think this is one of those things that only changes based on 'function name() {}' vs. 'var name = function() {}'

Comment: If the author of that article used it first it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Yeah. After reading the other link in your post, it seems that jQuery(document).ready(function () { is more appropriate for what I am trying to do. Gonna try using 'jquery' instead of '$' where appropriate and see if that helps. I am not a JS coder either so my fingers are crossed. Thanks!

Comment: Well, that only broke other things. Is it possible that the code that both myself and Vardhaman Deshpande posted is just not going to work?

Comment: No, that JS is valid. You should only replace the dollar signs when you are calling the jQuery library and not the SP libs.

Comment: Have you tried to debug this with the F12 developer tools? That way you can see when it's getting called and how far it's getting.

Answer (score 2):

If you have jQuery, why not go full jQuery? :)

Try this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("_layouts") != -1) {
       jQuery("#v5-page-column-sidebar").hide();
       jQuery("#v5-page-column-main").css({"width","100%"});
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks like it should work fine, but it doesn't seem to be applying to the div's as intended.

Comment: Is it getting applied? Are the divs being modified in any way?

Comment: The script does show on the pages but maybe it's not getting executed. There is no discernible difference from pages not in the _layouts folder.

Comment: Here is a link to a public page if you want to see it. I know you won't be able to see the pages in question, but at least you could see how the code is there. http://one.utsa.edu/sites/oit/OITConnect/infrastructureServices/Pages/VPN.aspx