# HTML button issue with internet explorer in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

HTML button works for other browser but it does not work for internet explorer.

```
<input id="submit1" type="button" value="Add" />
```

Comment: Do you mean the HTML doesn't create the button you'd expect? Which version of IE are you running?

Comment: It does not call the function, I am using IE-11, I have written JQuery function, in chrome it works fine but it does not work for explorer

Comment: Are you trying to use it as a submit-button? Would it be preferred to use the `input` as `type="submit"`?

Comment: Its not a submit button

Comment: Have you confirmed the jQuery is IE-compatible? There doesn't seem to be problems with the HTML

Comment: yes, jquery is also loaded..\

Comment: At last, i found that the problem was with the code. One of the variable was taking space with it like "username " which was ignored by chrome but it was taken by IE..

Answer (score 2):

Given the only code you provide:

```
<input id="submit1" type="button" value="Add" />
```

You can click this button but there is no action assigned to it.

Any clicks will propagate up the DOM and trigger **other** click events.

http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

#### Update 1 - But you problem is probably how you use jQuery

- [Risk of conflict between jQuery document ready and _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30500/risk-of-conflict-between-jquery-document-ready-and-spbodyonloadfunctionnames)
- https://www.spcaf.com/blog/sp-context-dev-part-6-jquery-vs-sharepoint/

[image]

Comment: Its something like dis...<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#submit1').click(function(){

});
</script>

Comment: Is the jQuery loaded properly before the page loads? You could confirm this e.g. by changing the click action to something like jQuery-type of alert text box and see whether the alert pops up

Comment: `$('#submit1').click(function(){console.log("click fired"); }); ` paste this the console of IE and then click on the button. let us know @vikashkumar

Comment: jQuery's ready function *can* conflict with SharePoint. Use proper SharePoint code: https://www.spcaf.com/blog/sp-context-dev-part-6-jquery-vs-sharepoint/

Comment: @AtishDipongkor, On Clicking the button, function is called..

Comment: did you try above answer